# What does AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask do?

Tags: ios

Apple added new class `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` recently,
But there is no informations about it.

Can you explain what is it exactly and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Its usage is as follow,

```
/*!
 @class         AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask
 @abstract      An AVAssetDownloadTask used for downloading multiple AVMediaSelections for a single AVAsset, under the umbrella of a single download task.
 @discussion    Should be created with -[AVAssetDownloadURLSession aggregateAssetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset:mediaSelections:assetTitle:assetArtworkData:options:. For progress tracking, monitor the delegate callbacks for each childAssetDownloadTask.
*/
```

**Note** If you cannot find any details in the documentation online, try to check it in its framework (I found the above in AVFoundation -> AVAssetDownloadTask.h file)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an answer: https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios/blob/master/OfflinePlayback.md#downloading-secondary-tracks-on-ios-11

> Subtitle, caption, and audio tracks are collectively known as "secondary tracks", and are downloaded differently on iOS 10.x, and ios 11+.

So in summary, it's used to download audio tracks, subtitles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually to download HLS videos (.m3u8 files) for offline playback on iOS.

The videos are formed of multiple chunks/segments, referenced in the .m3u8 playlist file so you can't easily download them (especially in the background) with a normal download task, so this class was added to facilitate that.

Generally speaking you simply give it a URL that references a .m3u8 and it will download to your device and you can then play it back offline.